# When researching an ip phone system, where would you start?

Tags: untagged

I'm one of the sysadmin's for our business and I've been tasked with researching and deploying a new IP based telephone system. I've got a solid grasp of our feature requirements, but what I don't have a grasp on in the available products.

I've deployed a couple [asterisk](/questions/tagged/asterisk) based systems in the past with success, but I don't want to rule out some of the more dedicated appliance based systems.

My problem is that I can't seem to find any sort of solid review site or system round-up whereby I can evaluate performance, features, and of course support.

Can anyone here help point me in the right direction in order for me to make an informed decision on the topic?

*I'm not looking for product or [shopping suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/2563/which-company-phone-do-you-recommend) here, just looking for research direction*

Comment: The top two in my eyes is simply Cisco Call Manager and Avaya...

Comment: We've been using Shoretel for 3+ years now. Easy system to maintain and use.

Comment: When researching an ip phone system, where would you start? Easy... Google

Comment: @ColdT as I said, not looking for product suggestions here, but thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @MichaelTodd same as above, but I do appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @t1nt1n I've been on google, but it's a big ocean with very little substance. I'm getting more "advertising" than true results.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to determine what the business requirements are.  Once you have that list it's simply a matter of stating conversations with Cisco, Microsoft etc, and have them set up.  If you simply have no existing relationships with a company that has an offering in this space, or if you want less biased opinions you need to find a VOIP company (eg WilTel Communications etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'directions', then 1st thing is to draw up top 5/10, then narrow down to your requirements/budget/implementation time. Trial out some of the services if its SAAS or get a demo item from a respected company... and go on from there... I also understand some people may go against top 5/10, cause there are plenty in the market that may be equally good or better but you want to go for a mature product ultimately with good support and updates.

- if you do have an account, take a look at this http://www.techrepublic.com/whitepapers/compare-ip-pbx-systems-from-leading-vendors-like-cisco-nortel-and-avaya/314497
- http://www.voip-news.com/whitepaper/voip-ip-pbx-comparison/

Comment: eek, register walls are a pain, but I'm at the point that I'll try anything. Thanks @ColdT. Can you explain 5/10?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find anything else for download and can't upload right this moment. To clarify, i just meant top 5 or top 10, depending on your timescale.

Answer (score -2):

google "ip phone system companies"

I can tell you that Places like Cisco, Shoretel, and ACT conferencing are all fairly well-known and respected.  You're going to want to look for more than just a low cost.

Always get the following:

- Price Quote
- Demo run of product
- Hardware requirements
- Support available
- Additional features
- Integration information with current system(s)
- Update schedule (and your role in said updates)
- At least 2-3 points of contact with each company

From there, compare the information you gathered, and make your decision.

Comment: might i ask why the downvote?